# How to use GeometricalAnalysisTools from the cloudComPy module

Tags: python, point-clouds

I installed the cloudComPy module to automate point-cloud processes in python otherwise done using the GUI of CloudCompare. Very important feature of this are the Geometrical Analysis Tools. However I do not understand how to use these in Python.

I find the documentation to be confusing: https://www.simulation.openfields.fr/documentation/CloudComPy/html/GeometricalAnalysisTools.html

It says `class cloudComPy.GeometricalAnalysisTools` contains several algorithms to compute point-clouds geometric characteristics (curvature, density, etc.).

However more information isn't there. Also a `dir(cc.GeometricalAnalysisTools)` call doesn't reveal any more necessary information about these functions.

I'm in the dark. Does anyone have more experience with cloudComPy?

Comment: I cannot help you. Have you tried posting the question on CloudComPy GitHub account?
https://github.com/CloudCompare/CloudComPy/issues

Answer (score 0):

this function is not well documented, but you can use it as such:

```
import cloudComPy as cc
...
dens = cc.Density
cc.computeLocalDensity(dens.DENSITY_2D, 0.05, [cloud])
```

where you can replace 2D by 3D or KNN, 0.05 is the radius you wish to use and [cloud] is a list of clouds to process.